# Disable subdomains in scrapy and filter links according to pattern

Tags: python, scrapy

In scrapy there's an option to constraint the crawling to certain domains, namely, putting them in allowed_domains variable.

1. How can I disallow crawler to run into certain subdomains?
2. How can I disallow crawler to follow links with certain pattern, e.g. that contain "?login=" or
3. Is there a possibility to follow only links that satisfy some regex pattern?

Answer (score -1):

How about [this](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html?highlight=deny#scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml.LxmlLinkExtractor)? I think the documentation is a good place to read -- where you can find your answer abut the `deny` parameter beside `allow` and that they work with regular expressions.